# Coupon Discount product bug

Tags: magento-1.9

im not sure if it is a bug, but something is not working right, basically i have a 10% discount coupon on products, but the calculations is not working right.

Basically it shows the correct price, and the correct discount amount, but than on the "Row Total" instead of showing in my case 27.53 it shows 26.83.

Here is a image of the item ordered.
[image]

And than here above is the options that i configure in the coupon rule.
[image]

Comment: Can you please add your config tax setting?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no other rule applying? Try setting option "Stop Further Rule Processing" to "Yes" and see if it gets correct result